# How to calculate multiple travel times using gmapsdistance?

Tags: google-maps, distance, google-maps-api, time, transit

I am trying to use gmapsdistance on R to calculate multiple transit times from Google Maps.

I have a Google API key and can generate transit travel times for one origin and one destination with the following code:

gmapsdistance("51.7788868858975,-1.48196518842103"
, "51.76732413,-1.233620597" ,"transit",
              "googleAPIKey")

However, i have a list of 1000+ origins and destinations in latitude and longitude that i want to find transit times and can only retrieve one at a time. I've tried to adapt the formula provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281911/how-to-calculate-distance-with-mulitiple-coordinates-using-mapdist-and-read-ch) to request multiple requests using GGMAP:

google_results <- rbind.fill(apply(subset(TravelExample, select=c("Origin", "Destination")), 1, function(x) 
    gmapsdistance(x[2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmapsdistance/gmapsdistance.pdf), x[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281911/how-to-calculate-distance-with-mulitiple-coordinates-using-mapdist-and-read-ch), "transit", "googleAPIKey")))

I get the following error:  Error in gmapsdistance(x[2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmapsdistance/gmapsdistance.pdf), x[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24281911/how-to-calculate-distance-with-mulitiple-coordinates-using-mapdist-and-read-ch), "transit", "googleAPIkey") : 
  Google maps is not able to find a route between origin and destination

I would use GGMAPS, but unfortunately you cannot request transit times from Google using the pakagage.

Any ideas how i can request multiple transit times using gmapsdistance?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing it within a loop. Here is a suggestion on how to do it

```
origin<-c("New+York","Washington+DC")
destination<-c("Philadelphia+PA","Willimington+DE","Harrisburg+PA")
NO<-length(origin)
ND<-length(destination)
time<-matrix(0, nrow = NO, ncol = ND)
for (i in 1:1:NO){
    for(j in 1:1:ND){
        time[i,j]<-gmapsdistance(origin[i],destination[j],mode="driving")$Time
    }
}
```

I have developed some preliminary code in Python in order to process multiple queries at the same time. You can find the preliminary verison in this link:
https://github.com/rodazuero/gmapsdistancePY but you will have to adapt it yourself to your own need. 
I hope this helps.

Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

The new version allows to perform multiple queries. See the following example:

> origin = c("Washington+DC", "New+York+NY", "Seattle+WA", "Miami+FL")
>
> destination = c("Los+Angeles+CA", "Austin+TX", "Chicago+IL")
>
> results = gmapsdistance(origin, destination, "driving", shape = "long")

It is available on github: github.com/rodazuero/gmapsdistance and will be shortly uploaded to CRAN